# Search files from a list for a string

Tags: bash, grep, io-redirection

I have a directory of text files, and each of those files contains a line "Feature Number: " followed by some number. I also have another text file with a list of the file names in the order I want to search them. I tried the following bash command:

```
while read LINE; do
  grep -i 'feature number' $LINE > outputFile.txt
done < ../listOfFiles.txt
```

but never receive any output.

`grep -f ../listOfFiles.txt p*.txt` doesn't return anything either, but

`read LINE < ../listOfFiles.txt; echo $LINE` does, and
`grep -i 'feature number' oneOfTheFiles.txt` does.

Which part of the command isn't working, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Note you are doing `grep -i '...' > output`. This will overwrite every time, you'd better use `>>` instead to append data.

Comment: That is a problem. Thanks.

Comment: Or just `xargs grep -i 'feature number' < ../listOfFiles.txt >output`

Comment: If you intend to truncate (delete old data) the contents of `outputFile.txt` everytime you run the command, you can just give the redirection scope to the whole block: `while read LINE; do grep -i 'feature number' "$LINE"; done < ../listOfFiles.txt > outputFile.txt`

Comment: For the benefit of future readers: If your problem is now solved, please either encourage one of the commenters to turn their comment into an answer so you can accept it, or create your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide an answer that summarizes all the helpful hints in the comments on the question:

**@fedorqui** points out that **by using `>` *inside* the loop, you overwrite the output file in *every iteration* of the loop**, so that in effect only the *last* iteration's output is captured in the output file.

An **immediate fix is to use `>>`** instead, which *appends* to an existing output file (or creates it, if it doesn't exist).

```
while read -r LINE; do
  grep -i 'feature number' "$LINE" >> outputFile.txt
done < ../listOfFiles.txt
```

Note that I've also made the snippet more robust:

- `read -r` ensures that input lines are read without interpretation of `\` chars. - leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed from each line, however.
- `"$LINE"` is now double-quoted to protect it from expansions by the shell; this is necessary, for instance, if the variable value contains spaces.

However, **`>>` appends to any *preexisting* `outputFile.txt`**, so if you ran the snippet multiple times, for instance, the file would keep growing.

---

To prevent that, you can either explicitly truncate (`: >outputFile.txt`) or remove (`rm -f outputFile.txt`) the output file beforehand, or, preferably, **take advantage of the simplification recommended by @konsoelbox**:

```
while read -r LINE; do
  grep -i 'feature number' "$LINE"
done < ../listOfFiles.txt > outputFile.txt
```

By **placing the output redirection - with `>` - at the *end* of the `while` loop, output from *all* iterations is captured as a whole, while replacing any preexisting file**.

---

Finally, **@tripleee** suggests a **more radical simplification that uses `xargs` instead of a `while` loop**:

```
xargs grep -h -i 'feature number' < ../listOfFiles.txt > outputFile.txt
```

This will (typically) result in a ***single* invocation of `grep` with *all* input lines passed as filename arguments**.

Aside from being shorter to write, this approach is *much more efficient*.
Note the use of `grep -h`, which suppress prefixing of matches with the name of the originating file.

*Caveat*: This **works fine as long as the filenames in `../listOfFiles.txt` have no embedded spaces**, as each such filename would be split into *multiple* arguments.

**To handle filenames with embedded spaces correctly**:

- If you have **GNU** `xargs`, **use `-d'\n'`** to ensure that each line is considered its own argument when passed to `grep`:

  ```
  xargs -d'\n' grep -h -i 'feature number' < ../listOfFiles.txt > outputFile.txt
  ```
- If you only have a **POSIX-compliant** `xargs`: **use `-I`**, which, however, means that **`grep` is invoked *once for each input line***.

  ```
  xargs -I % grep -i 'feature number' % < ../listOfFiles.txt > outputFile.txt
  ```
- Finally, if you have an **`xargs` version that supports `-0`** for processing NUL-separated input (e.g., GNU `xargs`, FreeBSD (OSX) `xargs`), you can use the following trick:

  ```
  xargs -0 grep -h -i 'feature number' \
     < <(tr '\n' '\0' < ../listOfFiles.txt) > outputFile.txt
  ```

Note that the `-0`-based approach is generally the most robust one, as it even supports arguments with embedded `\n` chars., but NUL-separated input isn't always readily available, as the need for the `tr` trick demonstrates.

Answer (score -1):

The grep command should be like this:

grep -inr "search string"

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the question, produces different output (`-n` prefixes output with [filename and] line number), and changes the search scope (`-r` searches any specified directories recursively).